# Determine the location of multiple static bodies based on their "gravitational" effect upon a dynamic point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, physics

**I am writing a SF story, and though I'm sure that I've violated most of science and math to the Andromeda Galaxy and back, I'd like this part at least to be mathematically accurate. Here is a run down of the problem:**

There's a group of objects known as 'the artifacts'. These artifacts have a mystical attraction to one another. This attraction functions along the same line as gravity, such that the attraction force (**F**) between any two artifacts is equal to $1/r^2$ (where r is the distance between the two artifacts). For this problem, all other forces acting on the artifacts can be ignored.

If the protagonists possess one of these artifacts and the means to measure the total force acting upon it, can they determine the position of the other artifacts (which can be considered to be unmoving)? The protagonists can reposition the artifact that they possess in between measurements.

How many measurements are needed if there are only 2 artifacts (including the one possessed by the protagonists)? 4 artifacts? 7? 8? Is there a general rule that tells you how many measurements are needed for N artifacts?

---

What I've done so far (which is basically just solving for the simplest system):

**Variables**

Known Artifact position -> ($X,Y,Z$)

Force on Known Artifact -> $F$

X-Component of Force on Known Artifact -> $F_X$

Y-Component of Force on Known Artifact -> $F_Y$

Z-Component of Force on Known Artifact -> $F_Z$

Unknown Artifact positions represented by ($X_1...X_N, Y_1...Y_N, Z_1...Z_N$)

Distance from Known Artifact to Artifact N -> $r_N$

**Equations**

$r_N = \sqrt{(X - X_N)^2 + (Y - Y_N)^2 + (Z - Z_N)^2}$

$F = 1/r^2$

$F_X = (X_N - X)/r_N^3$

$F_Y = (Y_N - Y)/r_N^3$

$F_Z = (Z_N - Z)/r_N^3$

**Solution for System of 2 Artifacts**

$r_1 = \sqrt{1/F}$

$X_1 = X + F_X\cdot r_1^3$

$Y_1 = Y + F_Y\cdot r_1^3$

$Y_1 = Z + F_Z\cdot r_1^3$

---

The system of 2 artifacts is trivial to solve, but the other solutions are more complex. Thank you in advance for your help. Also, is there a name for this type of math? I've been calling it reverse-trilateration.

Comment: Generally speaking, since you obtain three numbers per measurement, if there are $n+1$ artifacts you need to make $n$ measurements of the force on one of them (while moving it around) to locate the other $n$ (whose locations constitute $3n$ unknowns).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That makes intuitive sense, but I'd like an explanation, please. So forgive me for sounding like a math teacher, but...could you show your work?

Comment: @Teller Two questions: 1) how did you get the equations for $F_X,F_Y,F_Z$? Specifically, shouldn't it be $r_N^2$ in the denominator instead of $r_N^3$? And 2) do you know how many "enemies" there are?

Comment: 1A) I was looking at this question on physics exchange: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17285/split-gravitational-force-into-x-y-and-z-componenets. 1B) F, however, should be equal to $1/r^2$. 2) "Enemies"? If you mean "artifacts", the short answer is that no, I do not.

Comment: I could be incorrect about the $F_X, F_Y, F_Z$, but here's how I see it: If $F_X$ is the cosine times F and F = $1/r^2$, then $F_X = (1/r^2)(r_X/r) = (r_X/r^3) = (X_N - X)/r_N^3$.

Comment: @Teller Yes, it looks right now. 2) If you don't know how many artifacts there are, it's hard to get very specific. Say you're feeling a force in a certain direction. There could be several artifacts in a line, a one artifact close to you... you wouldn't be able to tell how many there were, or where they would be. (Or, there could be two artifacts on either side of the line of force, for example)

Comment: @NotNotLogical That's incorrect. Maybe you are thinking of a single data point, but the problem states that the known artifact can be moved around to obtain several data points. With enough data points it is possible to determine the location of the unknown artifacts; it should even be possible to determine how many unknown artifacts there are.

Comment: @Teller I see, thank you for the clarification. It's a very interesting question, I'll try to give it some thought when I get time. My first impression is that this problem is quite hard, and probably needs to be solved numerically - you might get a better response if you asked on a physics or even computer science forum.

Comment: @Teller Also, since this is for a fiction book, what are you looking for? Do you want explicit formulae (which I'm guessing don't exist), or just general info like how many sample locations would need to be used and so forth?

Comment: @NotNotLogical I don't need explicit formulas; just knowing that the above gravitational equations exist and are applicable will do. I can and will gloss over them in the text. I'm primarily interested in the number of sample locations that are needed. I would like some mathematical proof that the number is correct, so unless that can be done without showing the formulas I probably need to see them.

Answer (score 0):

At risk of appalling the physicists, I will attempt to answer what I think is your question.

If *the number of artifacts $N$ is unknown* then the problem becomes quite hard. There are two cases:

1. You let the system evolve, so that all artifacts, yours and theirs, move around. In this case you could compare the evolution with the equations of motion predicted to solve for the number and position of the artifacts. *However*, $n$-body problems such as this do not admit closed-form solutions: see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem).
2. You simply move the artifact around and take measurements, assuming no change in the other artifacts. In this case, the "gravitational attraction" will act as if *all the artifacts were gathered at their center of gravity*. For example, a tennis ball falling to Earth acts as though one giant "Earth entity" at the center of the planet is pulling it in. There is no way of telling how many particles are in the Earth or where they are, based solely on that information.

If *the number of artifacts $N$ is known* then, "in theory", there may be a solution.

You have $3N$ variables to determine, so you would need to take $3N$ measurements. Then you would get a giant non-linear system of equations which almost certainly would not be exactly solvable (but maybe in your book that's different!).

Any edits/corrections from offended physicists are more than welcome :)

Comment: "the "gravitational attraction" will act as if all the artifacts were gathered at their center of gravity." [This is only true for perfectly spherically symmetrical distributions of mass.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Much appreciated, but I don't that your Earth analogy works. The artifacts are much more similar to planets in a solar system than a single planet, and thankfully we don't all drift towards their center of gravity! It might be better to keep this abstract. I intentionally stripped the math down (discarding mass + gravitational constant, for example) to avoid thinking of this problem in real-world terms.

The link to the n-body problem is helpful. It gives me more examples to explore. Thanks.